# Which Lactobacillales (Lactic acid bacteria — LAB) strains are capable of degrading starch?

Tags: biochemistry, physiology, microbiology, bacteriology, metabolism

I've been researching bacteria strains but am having trouble finding amylolytic LAB strains with amylolytic and lactic acid producing character. The only species I've found, that are capable of amylolysis (correct me if I'm wrong) are *Lactobacillus amylovorus*, *Lactobacillus manihotivorans*, *Lactobacillus plantarum*.

If any, what other LAB strains provide amylolysis? Also, can anyone verify if the above strains also meet the criteria?

**Edit**

The keyword here is strains. Many species can degrade starch but most strains cannot.

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3458588/ L. acidophilus can be another species on the list.

Comment: http://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?lrl00500 Lactobacillus rhamnosus

Comment: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.5504/BBEQ.2011.0124 it is not that hard to find articles in the topic. there are many species with this ability

Comment: @inf3rno That's only partly true. e.g. Propionibacterium freudenreichii subsp. shermanii CIRM-BIAlT is able to metabolize lactose, although this trait is strain-dependent, since the Lac genes may have been acquired through a horizontal transfer event mediated by phage infection. Many strains can degrade starch but few species cannot.